# XNA 4.0 change texture on key press

Tags: c#, xna, textures

I've been getting into xna framework recently and I came across a problem.
This's my code and it didn't work

```
    // Constructor
    public Player()
    {
        texture = null;
        position = new Vector2(350, 900);
        moveSpeed = 10;
        textureTitle = "playerShip";
    }

    // Load
    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {
        texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>(textureTitle);
    }

    // Update
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        KeyboardState curKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (curKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
        {
            position.Y = position.Y - moveSpeed;
            textureTitle = "playerShip2";
        }
            if (curKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
            position.Y = position.Y + moveSpeed;
        if (curKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            position.X = position.X - moveSpeed;
        if (curKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            position.X = position.X + moveSpeed;

    }

    // Draw
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
    }
```

player's always being drawn as "playerShip"
(sorry for my English)

Comment: You have to call LoadContent() again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the first texture is loaded, if you're changing the name of the texture, you should call `Content.Load` again.

However, it's harder for the processor to keep reloading the images, and it's better done if the images are all loaded at once. So instead of recalling the `LoadContent()` part, you should make a second Texture2D, and change the texture directly, instead of changing the directory name.

Something like this:

```
//add this to your public variables
public Texture2D currentTexture = null;

// Load
public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
{
    texture  = Content.Load<Texture2D>("playerShip");
    texture2 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("playerShip2");
    currentTexture = texture;
}

// Update
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    KeyboardState curKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
    if (curKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
    {
        currentTexture = texture2;
    }
    //...
}

// Draw
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(currentTexture, position, Color.White);
}
```